# How do you find what module loaded by (e)udev is hanging the system?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, udev

I have two different kernels, one built with a bunch of device support and another with not as much device support.  The one with less device support boots fine on an older `P5K Pro` motherboard, the one with more hangs the entire system.

I have to use a PS/2 keyboard and skip loading/triggering (e)udevd (which means my USB keyboard won't work). I tried to narrow it down, if I don't load `80-drivers.rules` it doesn't hang (but no device support).  The contents of that file is:

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update

ACTION!="add", GOTO="drivers_end"

ENV{MODALIAS}=="?*", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load $env{MODALIAS}"
SUBSYSTEM=="tifm", ENV{TIFM_CARD_TYPE}=="SD", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load tifm_sd"
SUBSYSTEM=="tifm", ENV{TIFM_CARD_TYPE}=="MS", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load tifm_ms"
SUBSYSTEM=="memstick", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load ms_block mspro_block"
SUBSYSTEM=="i2o", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load i2o_block"
SUBSYSTEM=="module", KERNEL=="parport_pc", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load ppdev"
KERNEL=="mtd*ro", ENV{MTD_FTL}=="smartmedia", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load sm_ftl"
SUBSYSTEM=="scsi", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="scsi_device", TEST!="[module/sg]", RUN{builtin}+="kmod load sg"

LABEL="drivers_end"
```

On the kernel with less device support I see these devices:

```
Output of lsmod command (loaded modules):

Module                  Size  Used by
dm_mod                 86016  0
dax                    28672  1 dm_mod
rtl8187                40960  0
hid_generic            16384  0
mac80211              360448  1 rtl8187
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
sg                     28672  0
cfg80211              266240  2 mac80211,rtl8187
usbhid                 28672  0
hid                   106496  2 usbhid,hid_generic
sd_mod                 32768  4
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rtl8187
t10_pi                 16384  1 sd_mod
usb_storage            57344  0
sr_mod                 24576  0
cdrom                  28672  1 sr_mod
evdev                  20480  5
pcspkr                 16384  0
i2c_i801               24576  0
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
i2c_core               36864  2 i2c_smbus,i2c_i801
ata_generic            16384  0
uhci_hcd               28672  0
pata_acpi              16384  0
intel_nvme_remap       16384  0
firewire_ohci          36864  0
ahci                   45056  4
sky2                   53248  0
libahci                24576  1 ahci
pata_jmicron           16384  0
floppy                 61440  0
ehci_pci               16384  0
ehci_hcd               45056  1 ehci_pci
button                 16384  0
loop                   28672  0
edd                    16384  0

Output of lspci -knn command:

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller [8086:29c0] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8295]
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port [8086:29c1] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2938] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1a.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2939] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 [8086:293c] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:8277]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:294a] (rev 02)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: uhci_hcd
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
    Kernel modules: ehci_pci
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801IR (ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller [8086:2916] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard [1043:8277]
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:2822] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: intel_nvme_remap, ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P5K PRO Motherboard: 82801IR [ICH9R] [1043:8277]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] [10de:10c3] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:1302]
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be3] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:1302]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4364] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Motherboard [1043:81f8]
    Kernel driver in use: sky2
    Kernel modules: sky2
03:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller [197b:2363] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:824f]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
03:00.1 IDE interface [0101]: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB363 SATA/IDE Controller [197b:2363] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:824f]
    Kernel driver in use: pata_jmicron
    Kernel modules: pata_jmicron, pata_acpi, ata_generic
05:03.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: LSI Corporation FW322/323 [TrueFire] 1394a Controller [11c1:5811] (rev 70)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. LSI FW322/323 IEEE 1394a FireWire Controller [1043:8294]
    Kernel driver in use: firewire_ohci
    Kernel modules: firewire_ohci
```

Running udev (it's actually eudev), it always hangs with:

[image: pic of udev debug at point system hangs]

How do I find out what module is hanging the system? (The PS/2 keyboard won't work when it hangs, it's a full hang).   Sometimes the system just resets (turns off, comes back on).

TIA!!

Comment: Well, I did it the hard way, I just kept deleting module directories until it would work (well did it in a quicksort type of way - but there were dependencies that would not cause it to show up like if i2c wasn't loaded).   Anyway, it came down to nvidiafb module.   It's not the same as https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1044092-start-0.html but it looks like nvidia modules can cause problems in linux.